# How to get more information about 'feature' flag warning?

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, scala-2.10

When compiling an application with Play2, sometimes these kind of message appears on my terminal :

> [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to ~/target/scala-2.10/classes...
>   [warn] there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
>   [warn] one warning found 
>   [success] Compiled in 1s

How can I get more information about those warning? It must be an option of sbt but I have no idea where to search...

Comment: It is effect of SIP-18 http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/modularizing-language-features.html to the see warning add this flag in your sbt definition: `scalacOptions ++= Seq(... "-feature")`

Comment: Indeed! That worked, thanks! Would you mind suggesting an answer with that?

Comment: @i.am.michiel Exactly which file did you add it in PlayFramework 2? I am triying to add `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation","-feature")` to Build.scala but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I added to build.sbt, but I'm using Play 2.3.x

Comment: @UmutBenzer I had the same, no effect if it was alongside the other flags in 'build.sbt'. If I made a line for it itself (using ++=) I got the warnings. Weird.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To see the exact message you need to add "feature" flag in your sbt build definition file:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature")
```

Why? Scala 2.10 not only introduced new features, but also reshuffled older ones -- some of the most powerful scala features were hidden because they should be used with great responsibility: [sometimes they were used mistakingly](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-sips/W5CGmauii8A/ddXorbmJpJkJ). That is why [SIP-18](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/modularizing-language-features.html) has arised. From now on, to access dynamics, higher kinds, existential types and some other things you have to explicitly enable them.

Comment: If you want to do this on the command line just temporarily, use `set scalacOptions += "-feature"`