# How to run Play Framework 2.2.0 with -feature option

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

Seeing this in my console after running `play -> run`:

```
[warn] there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
[warn] one warning found
```

Where is this enabled? Would like to see what the warning is, but running `play -feature` or `run -feature` doesn't seem to do the trick.

I'm running Play Framework 2.2.0-scala

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533706/how-to-get-more-information-about-feature-flag-warning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-feature` is a compiler option - it must be passed to scalac.

To pass arguments to `scalac` in play or in any sbt build for that mattern you use the `scalacOptions` setting.

So add this in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalacOptions += "-feature"
```

Comment: Similarly, if it's project/Build.scala building your stuff, add 'object AppBuild extends Build { ... lazy val scalacOptions = Seq ( ... "-feature" ) .. } Some projects use project/Build.scala instead of build.sbt. (This is as a general helpful advice, Play probably uses build.sbt.)

Comment: or.. (to replace my earlier comment), if it's a `project/*.scala` file, make a `project/turtle.sbt` file that has the `scalacOptions` setting.